# Plot marker for each users location from database IP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a users table in my database that stores an ip address.
I have an api that gets the users latitude and longitude.

Firstly, I need to get every users lang and long.

At the moment, my code is only returning the last user in my database's lang and long.

This is my code for trying to return every clients long and langs:

```
$user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {

$username_   = $users_['username'];
$client_ip   = $users_['ip'];

//This is for getting each users location on our map
$ip               = $client_ip;
$geocode          = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}");
$output           = json_decode($geocode);
$client_latitude  = $output->latitude;
$client_longitude = $output->longitude;

}
```

Then I return this to my home PHP page using:

```
$response = array('client_latitude'=>$client_latitude,'client_longitude'=>$client_longitude); 
echo json_encode($response);
```

I recieve the AJAX request with the following JS / JQUERY code:

```
    <script>
    function fetchOnline() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_dash_settings.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_data:true},
            success: function(value) {
                var data = JSON.parse(value);
                $('#lat').html(data['client_latitude']);
                $('#long').html(data['client_longitude']);
            },
            complete:function(){
               setTimeout(fetchOnline,5000);
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { setInterval(fetchOnline,5000); });
</script>
```

And then finally, I try and display these in div's for testing.

Eventually, I want them to go in to the jVectorMap Markers JS code so It can plot markers on my map from each users lang and long.

But for now, It's not getting each users lang and long. Only the last user in my database's.

***UPDATED CODE***

The code Sumarai posted below isn't working.
It is not updating the div id - all-the-coordinates.
Does anyone know what's wrong with my version ?

I am using some different code to the question I asked. I have been using it from the start but didn't post it here because I didn't think it would be this difficult.

My new script is the same but I am calling them in separate files now because I am already calling an array in my other file (get_dash_settings).

This is my script in my main PHP file:

```
    <script>
    function fetchOnline() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_dash_settings.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_data:true},
            success: function(value) {
                var data = JSON.parse(value);
                $('#totalUsers').html(data['totalUsers']);
                $('#totalOnline').html(data['totalOnline']);
                $('#freeModeStatus').html(data['freemode']);
                $('#bypassesStatus').html(data['bypasses']);
                $('#isOnline').html(data['client_is_online']);
            },
            complete:function(){
               setTimeout(fetchOnline,5000);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_dash_map.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_data_:true},
            success: function(value_) {
                const data_ = JSON.parse(value_);
                const $parent = $('#all-the-coordinates');
                for (const row of data) {
                    const $element = $('<span></span>');
                    $element.text(`${data_['client_latitude']}, ${data_['client_longitude']}`);
                    $parent.append($element);
                }
            },
            complete:function(){
               setTimeout(fetchOnline,5000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { setInterval(fetchOnline, 5000); });
</script>
```

My get_dash_map.php:

```
$user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");

$response = [];

while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {
    $client_ip   = $users_['ip'];

    //This is for getting each users location on our map
    $ip               = $client_ip;
    $geocode          = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}");
    $output           = json_decode($geocode);
    $client_latitude  = $output->latitude;
    $client_longitude = $output->longitude;

    $response[] = ['client_latitude' => $client_latitude,'client_longitude' => $client_longitude];
}

echo json_encode($response);`
```

Comment: Try changing `$client_ip   = $users_['ip'];` to `$client_ip[]   = $users_['ip'];` since you want an array to hold them all.

Comment: @TheCodesee Thanks for your fast reply but this makes my AJAX not load atol.

Comment: I should not place too much faith in the results returned by `freegeoip` if I were you - it tells me that I'm in El Segundo, California, USA ( I'm in the UK ) so perhaps other users will appear in strange locations also

Comment: look at using `navigator.geolocation` built into browser and using ip as a fallback.....and store the location in db. You will run into use limits sending every user to that api every time a page is loaded not to mention the time it takes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to get a bunch of coordinates back, it makes sense to return them in an array of sorts. You are currently only getting the last one, because you are overwriting the values. Make an entry, then add that entry to the response as an array item. You can easily create a new array item with the `[]` suffix. `$response[] = $x` will add an array item to `$response` containing `$x`.

```
$user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");

$response = [];

while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {
    $client_ip   = $users_['ip'];

    //This is for getting each users location on our map
    $ip               = $client_ip;
    $geocode          = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}");
    $output           = json_decode($geocode);
    $client_latitude  = $output->latitude;
    $client_longitude = $output->longitude;

    $response[] = [
        'client_latitude' => $client_latitude,
        'client_longitude' => $client_longitude
    ];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

You obviously need to change your javascript too, as it currently expects an Object back with two keys, but you now get an Array of Objects back.

```
<script>
    function fetchOnline() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/get_dash_settings.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_data:true},
            success: function(value) {
                const data = JSON.parse(value);
                const $parent = $('#all-the-coordinates');
                for (const row of data) {
                    const $element = $('<span></span>');
                    $element.text(`${row['client_latitude']}, ${row['client_longitude']}`);
                    $parent.append($element);
                }
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { setInterval(fetchOnline, 5000); });
</script>
```

with in the html

```
<div id="all-the-coordinates"></div>
```

Comment: Okay thank you but when I use this, my information on my main PHP page won't load. when I use $response = array() it does.

Comment: Well, obviously you need to change your javascript function too, but I leave it to you to loop through the returned array and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. Can you give me a starting point ?

Comment: @Sumurai8 It still isn't working with that code buddy.

Comment: this code `$response = [];` is saying : syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: That syntax was introduced in php 5.4, released in March 2012. Please upgrade.

Comment: Because in what you copied you get the keys from `data` instead of `row`. Please do some of the debugging yourself.